# what is the use of the size attribute for button

Tags: html

HTML

```
 <input type="button" value="Click here" size="1"/>
```

Here what is the use of the size attribute for button. It does nothing.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/U6b5a/

Answer (score 2):

`size` is not `Permitted attributes` of `input type=button`, so it does nothing.

***[See the document](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.button.html)***.

Comment: A table on the w3c wiki that shows the same in a different, perhaps clearer way: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input#HTML_Attributes

Comment: @xdazz: `size is not permitted` is incorrect. It is very much permitted. However, it does not take effect in case of type="button.

Comment: @abhitalks xdazz was referring to the fact that on the linked page, `size` does not appear under the heading `Permitted Attributes`

Comment: @abhitalks I didn't say `size is not permitted`, the `Permitted attributes` means these attributes take effect while others do not.

Comment: @MistressDavid: there is a difference between *applies* and *permitted*, thats all i wanted to say.

Comment: is Size attribute applicable only for input type="text"?

Comment: @xdazz: your intention is right, but still is a permitted attribute. It does not apply is different imho.

Comment: @Johnny: it is applicable to search, tel, and url as well

Answer (score 1):

According to this on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

> The initial size of the control. This value is in pixels unless the
>   value of the type attribute is text or password, in which case, it is
>   an integer number of characters. Starting in HTML5, this attribute
>   applies only when the type attribute is set to text, search, tel, url,
>   email, or password; otherwise it is ignored. In addition, the size
>   must be greater than zero. If you don't specify a size, a default
>   value of 20 is used.

So, the size is certainly a valid attribute (unlike what many have posted here). But, it does not take effect unless the `type="text" / search / tel/ url` is specified. It is ignored in your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

For `Input type=button` Size `attribute` not `applicable` for changing  the  button size use `width` property

Try [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/V4Qq6/)

```
<input type="button" value="Click Here Okay" style="width:40px;"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

The size attribute works with the following input types:

```
text
search
tel 
url 
email
password.
```

See this:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp

if particularly u want to set the size means

By inline styling (css)  :`<input type="button" style="width: 100px"/>`